# "fread" function that causes segmentation fault

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// opens the memory 
FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r");
if(inptr == NULL)
{
    // checks for the availability of the file
    printf("Couldn't open card.raw\n");
    return 1;
}
char title[7];
int i = 0;
bool start = false;
BYTE* block = malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * 512);
while(fread(block, sizeof(BYTE), 512, inptr) == 512)
{
    if(fsign(block) && !start)
    {
        sprintf(title,"%.3d.jpg" , i);
        i++;
        FILE* image = fopen(title, "w");
        fwrite(block, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
        fclose(image);
    }
    else if(!fsign(block) && start)
    {
        FILE* image = fopen(title, "a");
        fwrite(block, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
        fclose(image);
    }

}
fclose(inptr);
free(block);
}

bool fsign(BYTE* block)
{
    if(*(block) == 0xff)
    {
        if(*(block + 1) == 0xd8)
        {
            if(*(block + 2) == 0xff)
            {
                if(*(block + 3) >= 0xe0 && *(block + 3) <= 0xef)
                { 
                     return true;
                }  
            }

        }

    }

return false;
```

So my question is in the while loop. The while loop iterates 3 times successfully and the fread function reads the file successfully each time of the three iteration; However, on the third iteration, fread causes a segmentation fault. why might that happen?

Comment: if this is supposed to be c++, why dont you use any c++ stuff? If it is supposed to be c, please remove the c++ tag

Comment: That's just the right point to learn how to use the debugger to step through your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sprintf(title,"%.3d.jpg" , i); will put a string value XXX.jpg to the title buffer, which is 7 bytes long.

However sprintf null terminates the string, so requires and additional buyte to store the null byte.